# How can I parse JSON to convert this to an array of objects in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

This is a sample of my json that is on my website:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "day": "Saturday 3/10",
    "title": "title1",
    "description": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "image": ""
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "day": "Saturday 10/10",
    "title": "title2",
    "description": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "image": ""
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "day": "Saturday 17/10",
    "title": "title3",
    "description": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "image": ""
}]
```

And now I want to save every object in an array of objects but it's possible that there are more than three elements. I think I have to use `NSJsonSerialization` because I have to get it from an url.

(I'm using swift 2)

Comment: how are you attempting to do this?  (feel free to show some code), and what is the problem that your running into?

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: How I can save the objects from an online json file in an array

Comment: Have you looked at NSJSONSerialization?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would personally do this using NSArrays and NSDictionaries to reference each object in your JSON.  Something like this should suffice (let `JSON` be your JSON variable)

```
if let array = JSON as? NSArray {
    for obj in array {
        if let dict = obj as? NSDictionary {
            // Now reference the data you need using:
            let id = dict.valueForKey("id")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the question is how to Parse the JSON into arrays and dictionaries- say via NSJSONSerialization

Comment: This code works fine but wasn't directly what I wanted. But it helped me. Thank you!

Comment: @Cailean Wilkinson can you please explain let JSON be your JSON variable? what will be the value of JSON variable

Answer (score 9):

There is an easy way to do this in Swift 4.x
But I had a difficult time getting to the simple answer so I'll post it here.

**Step 1** : Create a class that matches your JSON and is derived from Codable.
Here I arbitrarily name the class (that wraps your original JSON) as `BlogPost`.

You'll need to add an init method also

```
class BlogPost : Codable{
    var id : Int
    var day : Date
    var title : String
    var description : String

    init (id : Int, day : Date, title : String, description : String){
         self.id = id;
         self.day = day;
         self.title = title;
         self.description = description;
    }
}
```

**Step 2** : add a load method that will load your array.

It will take a filename (pointing to file with json) and return an array of BlogPost ([BlogPost])

```
 func loadJson(filename fileName: String) -> [BlogPost]? {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forAuxiliaryExecutable: fileName) {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let allBlogPosts = try decoder.decode([BlogPost].self, from: data)
                return allBlogPosts
            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

}

I think the tricky part is the type that you send to the decoder method.  Since we want to decode an array of Decodable BlogPost objects we have to use: `[BlogPost].self`

```
decoder.decode([BlogPost].self, from: data)
```

Comment: As of swift 5, you don't need an explicit init in codable struct - compiler will gently generate it automatically

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
if let JSONData = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) {
    do {
        let parsed = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray
        for obj in parsed! {
            let obj = MyObject(json: obj as! NSDictionary)
            list.append(obj)
        }
    } catch let parseError {
        print(parseError)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is with https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper, you can easly make objects from JSON and convert them back to JSON

```
class Event: Mappable {
    var id:String?
    var day:String?
    var title:String?
    var description:String?
    var image:String?

    required init?(map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id             <- map["id"]
        day            <- map["day"]
        title          <- map["title"]
        description    <- map["description"]
        image          <- map["image"]
    }
}
// make event from JSON
let event = Mapper<Event>().map(JSON)
// to JSON
event.toJSON()
```

just simple example,
I hope this will help to someone.